# Why does my favicon look terrible in Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: favicon, internet-explorer-7

I have a 32x32 favicon (in .ico format) that shows up fine in Firefox 3.6.12 and Chrome 5.0.375.70. But in Internet Explorer 7.0.5730.13 it looks terrible. It also looks bad in Windows Explorer (XP).

(Hmmm, I can't upload it - perhaps .ico format is blocked?)

(It's not IE8 but there is no other tag)

Comment: Re-tagged as IE7 for you.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the best site for this question. I believe the http://webmasters.stackexchange.com would be a better fit.

Comment: Perhaps a link to your favicon would be helpful

Comment: Or at the very least describe how it looks "terrible".

Comment: @John Conde - sorry, it's on a private (company) site. I tried uploading it but for some reason I couldn't - perhaps the software blocks .ico?

Comment: @Lèse majesté - good point, sorry. I think the *pixelated* comment in the answer below summarises it well. E.g. the image contains one letter, very clearly (in FF & GC). But in IE it is unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the solution, at least in my case, is to save in 32x32 .ico format but **with the transparency turned off**.

In addition - when I use this in MediaWiki it only goes wrong using the default name: **favicon.ico**. When I use a non default name, the problem goes away!

In Local Settings.php:

```
$wgFavicon = '<name>.ico';
```

Comment: You will have to look into it deeper but IE doesn't look at the favicon link it instead looks for a file in your root folder with the name favicon.ico so technically you can use different files for different browsers.  Check out http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/promotion/favicon.html

Comment: @RandomBen - well, it definitely changed when I used non-default, which is weird. Thanks for the feedback. Good tip about different files for different browsers - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this question on Stack Overflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031718/favicon-is-pixelated-in-ie.

It looks like 32x32 pixel favicons look much better in IE7 than 16x16.  The only down side is Chrome only supports 16x16.

Here is an article going in depth into how favicons work and what your options are, http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/10/17/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-favicons/.

Comment: @RandomBen - that looks great, thank you. I will try it (32x32) out and get back to you.

Comment: @RandomBen - having said that, at the SO answer there does not seem to be a one size fits all - it looks like I need to choose between IE & Chrome. Perhaps I should not use .ico?

Comment: @RandomBen - clarified question - I checked again: the icon *is* in 32x32. OK in Chrome, NOK in IE7 - which is the opposite of your response. Weird.

Comment: @RandomBen - I've tried 16x16 and 32x32 versions of the icon, in .ico & .jpg format - all failed in IE.

Comment: @RandomBen - also, only .ico preserves transparency (the icon is round, not square).

Comment: @Mark - Earlier versions of IE do have issues with transparent images.  I know IE6 has a problem but I am not sure about IE7.

Comment: @RandomBen - OK, thx.